# How to plot frequencies of words vs. time, with time variable grouped into month/year and year in R

Tags: r, date, plot, grouping

I have a document term matrix, with frequencies of >600 words, and a corresponding date (mm/dd/yyyy) for each frequency value:

```
     > head(mydata3,3)
  Claim.Number  Note.Date  LOSSDATE DATEREPORTED
1       106810  7/10/1998 12/9/1997   12/29/1997
2       106810  7/21/1998 12/9/1997   12/29/1997
3       106810 10/21/1999 12/9/1997   12/29/1997
  DATEENTERED Row Topic absenc abus academ access
1    1/5/1998   3     4      0    0      0      0
2    1/5/1998   4     2      0    0      0      0
3    1/5/1998   8    11      0    0      0      0
  accid accommod account accus act action activ add
1     0        0       0     0   0      0     0   0
2     0        0       0     0   0      0     0   0
3     0        0       0     0   0      0     0   0
  addit addl adequ adjust administr admiss advanc
1     0    0     0      0         0      0      0
2     0    0     0      0         0      0      0
3     0    0     0      0         0      0      0
  advers advic african age agenc agreement aid ambul
1      0     0       0   0     0         0   0     0
2      0     0       0   0     0         0   0     0
3      0     0       0   0     0         0   0     0
  amount analysi ankl answer anticip appeal appel
1      0       0    0      0       0      0     0
2      0       0    0      0       0      2     0
3      0       0    0      0       0      1     0
  appli applic appoint appropri approv approxim arbitr
1     0      0       0        1      0        0      0
2     0      0       0        0      0        0      0
3     0      0       0        0      0        0      0
  argu argument aris arm arrang arriv asap assault
1    0        0    0   0      0     0    0       0
2    0        0    0   0      0     0    0       0
3    0        0    1   0      0     0    0       0
  assert assess assist athlet attach attent audit auto
1      0      0      0      0      0      2     0    0
2      0      0      0      0      0      0     0    0
3      0      0      0      0      0      0     0    0
  avoid await award background balanc ball bar basi
1     0     0     0          0      0    0   0    0
2     0     0     0          0      0    0   0    0
3     0     0     0          0      0    0   0    0
  benefit big bill black board breach break. brief
1       0   0    0     0     0      0      0     0
2       0   0    0     0     0      0      0     0
3       0   0    0     0     0      0      0     0
  broken broker budget build bus busi call campus cap
1      0      0      0     0   0    0    0      0   0
2      0      0      0     0   0    0    2      0   0
3      0      0      0     0   0    0    0      0   0
  car care carrier center cgl chair chang charg child
1   0    0       0      0   0     0     0     0     0
2   0    0       0      0   0     0     0     0     0
3   0    0       0      0   0     0     0     0     0
  children circuit cite citi civil clean client clinic
1        0       0    0    0     0     0      0      0
2        0       0    0    0     0     0      0      0
3        0       0    0    0     0     0      0      0
  close closur cmc coach code collect commit committe
1     0      0   0     0    0       0      0        0
2     0      0   0     0    0       0      0        0
3     0      0   0     0    0       0      0        0
  communic compani compar compel compens complain
1        0       0      0      0       0        0
2        0       0      0      0       0        0
3        0       0      0      0       0        0
  complet conclud condit conduct conf confer confid
1       0       0      0       0    0      0      0
2       0       0      0       0    0      0      0
3       0       0      0       0    0      0      0
  conflict connect construct consult contact contend
1        0       0         0       0       0       0
2        0       0         0       0       0       0
3        0       0         0       0       0       0
  contract contractor contribut control convers
1        0          0         0       0       0
2        0          0         0       0       0
3        0          0         0       0       0
  convinc cooper coordin copi correct cost counter
1       0      0       0    0       0    0       0
2       0      0       0    0       0    0       0
3       0      0       0    1       0    0       0
  counti cours court cover coverag creat credibl
1      0     0     0     0       0     0       0
2      0     0     0     0       0     0       0
3      0     0     0     0       0     0       0
  credit crimin cross cut damag danger deadlin deal
1      0      0     0   0     0      0       0    0
2      0      0     0   0     0      0       0    0
3      0      0     0   0     0      0       0    0
  dean death decis declin deduct defam defect defend
1    0     0     0      0      0     0      0      0
2    0     0     0      0      0     0      0      0
3    0     0     0      0      0     0      0      0
  degre delay demand deni denial depart depos deposit
1     0     0      0    0      0      0     0       0
2     1     0      0    1      0      0     0       0
3     1     0      0    0      0      0     0       0
  dept despit develop diari difficult director disabl
1    0      1       0     1         0        0      0
2    1      0       0     0         0        0      0
3    0      0       0     0         0        0      0
  discharg disciplin disciplinari discoveri discrimin
1        0         0            0         0         1
2        0         0            0         0         1
3        0         0            0         0         0
  discuss dismiss disput distress district doc docket
1       0       0      0        0        0   0      0
2       0       0      0        0        0   0      0
3       0       0      0        0        0   0      0
  doctor document done door dorm doubt draft drive
1      0        0    0    0    0     0     0     0
2      0        0    0    0    0     0     1     0
3      0        0    0    0    0     0     0     0
  driver drop due earlier earn educ eeoc effort ell
1      0    0   0       0    0    0    0      0   0
2      0    0   0       0    0    0    0      0   0
3      0    0   0       0    0    0    0      0   0
  els email emot employ employe encourag end endors
1   0     0    0      0       0        0   1      0
2   0     0    0      0       0        0   0      0
3   0     0    0      1       2        0   1      0
  enrol entitl environ estim evalu event evid exam
1     0      0       0     0     0     0    0    2
2     0      0       0     0     0     0    0    2
3     0      0       0     0     0     0    0    2
  examin exceed excess exchang exclus execut expens
1      0      0      0       0      0      0      0
2      0      0      0       0      0      0      0
3      0      0      0       0      0      0      0
  experi expert expir exposur extend extens extent
1      0      0     0       0      0      0      0
2      0      0     0       0      0      0      0
3      0      0     0       0      0      0      0
  extrem eye face facil faculti fail failur fall fals
1      0   0    0     0       0    0      0    0    0
2      0   0    0     0       1    2      1    0    0
3      0   0    0     0       0    3      0    0    0
  fault favor fax feder fee fell femal field fight
1     0     0   0     0   0    0     0     0     0
2     0     0   0     0   0    0     0     0     0
3     0     0   0     0   0    0     0     0     0
  final financi finish fire firm floor focus foot forc
1     0       0      0    0    0     0     0    0    0
2     0       0      0    0    0     0     0    0    0
3     0       0      0    0    0     0     0    0    0
  form formal former forward fractur free fund futur
1    0      0      0       0       0    0    0     0
2    0      0      0       0       0    0    0     0
3    0      0      0       0       0    0    0     0
  game gender gone grade graduat grant grievanc ground
1    0      0    0     0       0     0        0      0
2    0      0    0     0       0     1        0      0
3    0      0    0     1       1     0        0      0
  group hand happi harass head health hear held higher
1     0    0     0      0    0      0    0    0      0
2     0    0     0      0    0      0    0    0      0
3     0    0     0      0    0      0    0    0      0
  hire histori hit hold home hospit hostil hous human
1    0       0   0    0    0      0      0    0     0
2    0       0   0    0    0      0      0    0     0
3    0       0   0    0    0      0      0    0     0
  ice identifi immedi immun impact import impress
1   0        0      0     0      0      0       0
2   0        0      0     0      0      0       0
3   0        0      0     0      0      0       0
  improv inappropri inclin incur indemn individu injur
1      0          0      0     0      0        0     0
2      0          0      0     0      0        0     0
3      0          0      0     0      0        0     0
  injuri inquir inquiri inspect instruct intent
1      0      0       0       0        0      0
2      0      0       0       0        0      0
3      0      0       0       0        0      0
  interest intern invoic job joint judg judgment juri
1        0      0      0   0     0    0        0    0
2        0      0      0   0     0    0        0    0
3        0      1      0   0     0    0        0    0
  jurisdict key knee knowledg lacer lack larg latest
1         0   0    0        0     0    0    0      0
2         0   0    0        0     0    0    0      0
3         0   0    0        0     0    0    0      0
  law lawyer layer learn leav leg legal letter level
1   0      0     0     0    0   0     0      1     0
2   0      1     0     0    0   0     0      0     0
3   0      0     0     0    0   0     0      0     0
  liabil lien life limit litig live lmtcb local lose
1      0    0    0     0     0    0     0     0    0
2      0    0    0     0     0    0     0     0    0
3      0    0    0     0     0    0     0     0    0
  loss lost low mail mainten major male manag materi
1    0    0   0    0       0     0    0     0      0
2    0    0   0    0       0     0    0     0      0
3    0    0   0    0       0     0    0     0      0
  mcad med mediat medic medicar meet memo merit messag
1    0   0      0     0       0    0    0     0      0
2    0   0      0     0       0    0    0     0      0
3    0   0      0     0       0    2    0     0      0
  million minor mom money monitor motion msj mtd
1       0     0   0     0       0      0   0   0
2       0     0   0     0       0      0   0   0
3       0     0   0     0       0      0   0   0
  nation near neck neglig negoti news noth notic
1      1    0    0      0      0    0    0     0
2      0    0    0      0      0    0    0     0
3      0    0    0      0      0    0    0     0
  notifi numer nurs object oblig ocr offer offici ongo
1      0     0    0      0     0   0     0      0    0
2      0     0    0      0     0   0     0      0    0
3      0     0    0      0     0   2     0      0    0
  open oper opinion opportun oppos opposit oral order
1    0    0       0        0     0       0    0     0
2    1    0       0        0     0       0    0     0
3    0    0       0        0     0       0    0     0
  origin outlin outstand owe paid pain park parti
1      0      0        0   0    0    0    0     0
2      0      0        0   0    0    0    0     0
3      0      0        0   0    0    0    0     0
  partner pass pay payment pend perman personnel petit
1       0    1   0       0    0      0         0     0
2       0    1   0       0    0      0         0     0
3       0    2   0       0    1      0         0     0
  phone photo physic physician pictur plan player
1     0     0      0         0      0    0      0
2     0     0      0         0      0    0      0
3     0     0      0         0      0    0      0
  plead poa polic polici poor postpon potenti practic
1     0   0     0      0    0       0       0       0
2     0   0     0      0    0       0       0       0
3     0   0     0      0    0       0       0       0
  preliminari premis prepar pres presid press pressur
1           0      0      0    0      0     0       0
2           0      0      0    0      0     0       0
3           0      0      0    0      0     0       0
  prevail prevent primari privat proceed product
1       0       0       0      0       0       0
2       0       0       0      0       0       0
3       0       0       0      0       0       0
  profession professor progress project promis promot
1          0         0        0       0      0      0
2          0         1        0       0      0      0
3          0         2        0       0      0      0
  proper properti propos protect provis provost pull
1      0        0      0       0      0       0    0
2      0        0      0       0      0       1    0
3      0        0      0       0      0       0    0
  punit pursu push qualifi quick quiet quit race rais
1     0     0    0       0     0     0    0    0    0
2     0     0    0       0     0     0    0    0    0
3     0     0    0       0     0     0    0    0    0
  rang rate reach recal receipt recov recoveri rediari
1    0    0     0     0       0     0        0       0
2    0    0     0     0       0     0        0       0
3    0    0     0     0       0     0        0       0
  reduc reimburs reinsur reject relationship releas
1     0        0       0      0            0      0
2     0        0       0      0            0      0
3     0        0       0      0            0      0
  relief remain remedi remov renew reopen rep repair
1      0      0      0     0     0      0   0      0
2      0      0      0     0     0      0   0      0
3      0      0      1     0     0      0   0      0
  repeat. replac repli repres represent research
1       0      0     0      0         0        0
2       0      0     0      0         0        0
3       0      0     0      0         0        0
  reserv resid resign resolut resolv respect respond
1      0     0      0       0      0       0       0
2      0     0      0       0      0       0       0
3      0     0      0       0      0       0       0
  rest retain retali retent retir return reveal review
1    0      0      0      0     0      0      0      2
2    0      0      0      0     0      0      0      0
3    0      0      0      0     0      0      0      1
  revis risk role ror rts rule run safeti salari
1     0    0    0   0   0    0   0      0      0
2     0    0    0   0   0    0   0      0      0
3     0    0    0   0   0    0   0      0      0
  schedul search section secur select semest separ
1       0      0       0     0      0      0     0
2       0      0       0     0      0      0     0
3       0      0       0     0      0      0     0
  serious serv servic settl settlement sex sexual
1       0    0      0     0          0   0      0
2       0    0      0     0          0   0      0
3       0    0      0     0          0   0      0
  shoulder side sidewalk sign signific sir sit site
1        0    0        0    0        0   0   0    0
2        0    0        0    0        0   0   0    0
3        0    0        0    0        0   0   0    0
  situat slip small snow speak spent split staff stage
1      0    0     0    0     0     0     0     0     0
2      0    0     0    0     0     0     0     0     0
3      0    0     0    0     0     0     0     0     0
  stair standard statement status statut step stop
1     0        0         0      0      0    0    0
2     0        0         0      2      0    0    0
3     0        0         0      0      0    0    0
  stori strategi street strike struck studi subject
1     0        0      0      0      0     0       0
2     0        0      0      0      0     0       0
3     0        0      0      0      0     0       0
  substanti success sue suffer suffici suggest summari
1         0       0   0      0       0       0       0
2         0       0   0      0       0       0       0
3         0       0   0      0       0       0       0
  supervis supervisor supplement supv surgeri suspect
1        0          0          0    0       0       0
2        0          0          0    0       0       0
3        0          0          0    0       0       0
  suspend sustain system tabl tcw teach teacher team
1       0       0      0    0   0     0       0    0
2       0       0      0    0   0     0       0    0
3       0       0      0    0   0     0       0    0
  telephon tender tenur term termin test testifi
1        0      0     0    0      0    0       0
2        0      0     0    0      0    1       0
3        0      0     0    0      0    0       0
  testimoni theori threaten titl top total tpa track
1         0      0        0    0   0     0   0     0
2         0      0        0    0   0     0   0     0
3         0      0        0    0   0     0   0     0
  train transcript transfer transport travel treat
1     0          0        0         0      0     0
2     0          0        0         0      0     0
3     0          0        0         0      0     0
  treatment trial trip troubl tuition unabl unclear
1         0     0    0      0       0     0       0
2         0     0    0      0       0     0       0
3         0     0    0      0       0     0       0
  unfortun upcom updat vacat valu vehicl verdict video
1        0     0     1     0    0      0       0     0
2        0     0     0     0    0      0       0     0
3        0     0     0     0    0      0       0     0
  violat visitor voicemail wage wait walk warn watch
1      0       0         0    0    0    0    0     0
2      0       0         0    0    0    0    0     0
3      0       0         0    0    0    0    0     0
  water weak white win withdraw worker write written
1     0    0     0   0        0      0     0       0
2     0    0     0   0        0      0     0       0
3     0    0     0   0        0      0     1       0
  wrote xbocx xdolx ximex xmsjx xnpcx xoopx xprosex
1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0       0
2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0       0
3     1     0     0     0     0     0     0       0
  xsolx
1     0
2     0
3     0
```

I am trying to group the frequency values by month/year and year. For example, for the word "appeal", instead of having 2 occurrences on 1/5/1998, and another occurrence on 1/5/1998, I would like to have 3 occurrences for 1/1998, and then also 3 occurrences (assuming there aren't any more hits for the rest of the year) for 1998. Then I would like to plot the frequency per month/year vs. month/year, and the frequency per year vs. year.

I tried using the following code to group by month/year:

```
df %>%
      mutate(month_year = format(date, "%Y/%m")) %>%
      group_by(month_year) %>%
      summarise(total = sum(vocabfreq))
```

where value are all of the columns with the frequency of words in the original data set. Another problem is that my data set is quite large, and I am having difficulty plotting multiple series on one graph that shows distinctive features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xts` method:

```
library(xts)
dat <- data.frame(date=c('7/10/2014', '7/10/2014', '7/11/2014', '8/05/2015', '9/21/2015'),
                  word1= c(1,2,1, 4, 3), word2=c(3, 10, 1, 2, 4))
dates <- as.POSIXct(dat$date, format='%m/%d/%Y')
dat.xts <- xts(subset(dat, select= -date), order.by=dates)
apply.daily(dat.xts, colSums)
apply.monthly(dat.xts, colSums)
```

Comment: when I try this, the date column is not included in the data frame?

Comment: It's not a data.frame, it's an xts object. dates can be retrieved via `index(dat.xts)`. This is a much more efficient way to handle date data.

Comment: Also it would have been good to put a reproducible example in your question so we could give you an example using your data. See `?dput`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `summarise_each` instead of `summarise`. Btw, I'm using @DunderChief's code to generate the data. Thank you for that.

```
dat <- data.frame(date=c('7/10/2014', '7/10/2014', '7/11/2014', '8/05/2015', '9/21/2015'),
              word1= c(1,2,1, 4, 3), word2=c(3, 10, 1, 2, 4))
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format='%m/%d/%Y')) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum(.)))
```

Comment: when i try this on my data set i get a Error: sum not defined for "Date" objects

Comment: @Learning_R Oh, the reason is that you have other date columns in your data file while `.` means every column other than the grouping column. You cannot use `sum` on those Date object

Comment: @Learning_R You should either put all the date-columns into group_by or think of a good way to organize your date columns.